# Theorem 16.4 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Does the coincidence of the subspace and the (restricted) order topology imply ...?

Tags: general-topology

Here is Theorem 16.4 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ be an ordered set in the order topology; let $Y$ be a subset of $X$ that is convex in $X$. Then the order topology on $Y$ is the same as the topology $Y$ inherits as a subspace of $X$.

And, here is Munkres' definition of a subset $Y$ of $X$ to be convex in $X$:

> Given an ordered set $X$, let us say that a subset $Y$ of $X$ is *convex* in $X$ if for each pair of points $a < b$ of $Y$, the entire interval $(a, b)$ of points of $X$ lies in $Y$.

Now my question is, if $X$ is an ordered set in the order topology and if $Y$ is a subset of $X$ such that the order topology on $Y$ is the same as the topology $Y$ inherits as a subspace of $X$, then can we prove that $Y$ is convex in $X$?

My Attempt:

> Suppose $Y$ is not convex in $X$. Then there exist points $a, b \in Y$ such that $a < b$, but $(a, b) \colon=\left\{ \ x \in X \ \colon \ a < x < b \ \right\} \not\subset Y$; that is, there is some point $c \in X \setminus Y$ such that $a < c < b$.

What next?

Comment: Observe that $Y:=(0,1)\cup(2,3)\subset\mathbb R$ is not convex while order topology on $Y$ and subspace topology on $Y$ coincide. So the answer to your question is: no.

Answer (score 0):

You *can*  prove the following useful fact: suppose $(X, <_X)$ is an ordered topological space, and $O \subseteq X$ is open (in the order topology of course).

Then on $O$ the subspace topology and the relative-order topology coincide.

So sets like $(a,b) \cup (c,d)$ with $a < b < c < d$ as subsest of $\mathbb{R}$ are examples of non-convex such sets.